# What are these furigana (or punctuation marks)?

Tags: punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do Japanese writers use underline for emphasis?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1735/do-japanese-writers-use-underline-for-emphasis)

What do the punctuation marks next to あだ and はるひ mean?

[image: furigana 2]
[image: FURIGANA]

I can type the sentences, or show the passage if it helps.

Comment: I see 傍点 on あだ and はるひ, but I don't see any furigana on them.

Comment: FYI -　[http://www.weblio.jp/content/傍点](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%82%8D%E7%82%B9)

Comment: Haha, I don't see any either. I'll edit the q.

Comment: Seems highly unlikely someone googling to find out what the ゴマ are will land on the question Troyen links to.

Comment: Clear-cut case of duplicate: closing and adding redirect. (BTW, @louis: we prefer to avoid duplication of content at all costs, please recommend a 'close as duplicate' in such cases, rather that re-posting the answer).

Comment: @Louis That's correct, but we still want the best answers in one place.  Duplicates aren't necessarily bad, they serve to point people who were searching for different terms to the original question.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I thought the question would be deleted.