# What do comma-like marks along a word mean?

Tags: punctuation

What do comma-like marks along the word 捨て思い mean on book scan below?

[image: comma-like marks]

**Update**: ah, seems to be duplicate of [What are these furigana (or punctuation marks)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2768/what-are-these-furigana-or-punctuation-marks) and [Do Japanese writers use underline for emphasis?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1735/do-japanese-writers-use-underline-for-emphasis)
Nevermind then, thanks!