# Why are points used where furigana would be normally?

Tags: orthography, punctuation, furigana, symbols

Sometimes in mangas there are points where you would expect normally furigana. What meaning is it supposed to have?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do Japanese writers use underline for emphasis?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1735/do-japanese-writers-use-underline-for-emphasis)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The dots, called [傍点【ぼうてん】](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%82%8D%E7%82%B9-8733#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88) (or [圏点【けんてん】](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%9C%8F%E7%82%B9-492771#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88)), function like italics or underline with the Latin alphabet. They are for emphasis.

To see the effect in rōmaji:

> futatabi *kanojo jishin* no kuchi kara kiku koto ni naru to wa

***Update***. To answer the question in the comments, 傍点 and ふりがな may be combined (although ふりがな may also be omitted, as in the snippet in the question body). ONE PIECE isn't exactly a case study of minimalist typography (I'm counting at least 7 text fonts), but for completeness here is an example of 傍点 *on top of* (or rather, to the side of) ふりがな:

[image: 傍点とふりがな]

***Update 2***. Note that 傍点 may take different shapes. In Japanese both `●` and `﹅` are common. For more information see

- [圏点](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9C%8F%E7%82%B9) (Japanese Wikipedia)
- [Emphasis point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphasis_point) (English Wikipedia)

Usually a text would use one type of 傍点, but just for its curiosity value here is a snippet of a book by Miyatake Gaikotsu titled 奇態流行史 and published in 1922 with a rather eclectic use of emphasis points:

[image: 奇態流行史]

Comment: As a point of interest, what happens if furigana are needed as well as the 傍点?

Comment: @SimonGill At least in the manga of the question, the ふりがな seem to have simply been omitted. 口, 聞く, and 事 are all more basic than 彼女 and 自身, but have ふりがな, whereas 彼女 and 自身 just have 傍点.

Comment: @SimonGill, I'm fairly certain that I've seen cases of both ルビ and 傍点 on top of each other... but can't seem to find any cases online.

Comment: @SimonGill Please see the update.