# Why does some manga have dots above some of the words?

Tags: orthography, manga, punctuation

Potential spoilers for readers of Jojo, but in the top-left-hand corner of [this picture](http://i168.photobucket.com/albums/u168/Jesusfreekao/66_02-03.jpg) there are dots above the word こいつ.

[image]

Why do some manga have dots above some of the words? I've only noticed this in Jojo so far but perhaps it's in other manga too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are points used where furigana would be normally?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15270/1628)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the Japanese version of [underlining]{LLLLLLLLLLL}.  It's a way of marking a word for emphasis.

**Update**

The Japanese name for this is variously 圏点{けんてん} (literally "enclosing mark"), 傍点{ぼうてん} ("off-to-the-side mark"), or 脇点{わきてん} ("on-the-side mark").  The JA wikipedia [has a good article about this](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9C%8F%E7%82%B9).

Veteran user [snailplane](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/1478/snailplane) commented with this [meta](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-japanese-language-se/1294#1294) link, which shows how to use Japanese emphasis, like this: [強調]{﹅﹅}.

Comment: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-japanese-language-se/1294#1294

Comment: @snailplane, thanks, but what I was lamenting was the inability to use <u> or other underlining for non-Japanese text.  This{LLLL} doesn't work, for instance.

Comment: Hmm, how about [this]{LLLL}?

Comment: @snailplane -- what did you do in your edit?  It works now!  But the side-by-side marked-up edit summary view doesn't show me any changes...??

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have time to reply and explain.  I'll do that now.  The examples in the meta post have a zero-width space before the { to prevent it from working, as explained [here](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/807/1478), because otherwise you wouldn't be able to see what the markup looks like. You copied and pasted it including that zero-width space, which prevented it from working, but if you simply type it in, it should work fine.

Comment: Gah.  How frustrating.  Why not use the entity instead of the literal character?  That's at least visible when viewing the source in **Edit** mode.  Oh, well.  Thank you for the fix!

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to load the picture myself, but it is probably used for emphasis. Similar to ALL CAPS or periods after single words like "OH. MY. GOSH." in English.