# In vertical writing, what do these signs (that look like backticks) mean?

Tags: orthography

This is an extract from 窓ぎわのトットちゃん。

The teacher is talking about how Totto-chan ended up drawing a ふさ around her rendition of the flag of Japan. She is presumably quite astonished at this and my only guess is that these signs are used to express that astonishment? Not sure.

[image: ふさ backticks]

Comment: I updated my answer on [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15270/1628). I think this should answer your question.